# Identify distributions in histogram

Tags: python, distribution

As part of an implementation of image segmentation functionality, I'm trying to find a way to determine if there are multiple Gaussian distribution withing the data.
is there a method I can use to accomplish that?

[image]

Comment: You need [Gaussian Mixture Model](https://towardsdatascience.com/gaussian-mixture-models-explained-6986aaf5a95), in Python it is in sklean, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html. Some 1d example  https://www.astroml.org/book_figures/chapter4/fig_GMM_1D.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not a "code" problem. To fit a Gaussian you can use scipy.curve_fit but the hard part of this task is to identify the domains to fit.
First of all I woul use a larger binning for the histogram to avoid all the peaks you have in the right region of the histogram. Then you can use some algorithm to find the peaks and try to fit them in a certain range before and after the peak. You can accept the fit if the chi square or some other "loss function" is low enough or you can discard it and search the next one.